# Prolog: Making a procedure to print Hello World

Tags: procedure, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I want to load this simple something into my Editor:

```
Write:-repeat,write("hi"),nl,fail.
```

So that it prints "hi".

What should I do?

I'm currently trying to do `File->New`

and Saving a file named Write into `E:\Program Files\pl\xpce\prolog\lib`

When doing the query:

?-Write.

It's printing:

```
1 ?- Write.
% ... 1,000,000 ............ 10,000,000 years later
% 
%       >> 42 << (last release gives the question)
```

**Why?**

Comment: By the way, that "error message" is a reference to The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy.

Comment: I know. I love those books, but I find that message pretty dumb. It's a forced and obfuscating joke.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**

I did some more research. Apparently this is what SWI-Prolog does when you ask it about an uninstantiated variable.

```
$ prolog
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.6.64)
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 University of Amsterdam.
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- X.
% ... 1,000,000 ............ 10,000,000 years later
% 
%       >> 42 << (last release gives the question)
?-
```

**UPDATE**

Changing the name to lowercase works. Uppercase is for variables:

helloworld.prolog:

```
helloworld:-write('Hello World!'),nl,fail.
```

Then:

```
$ prolog
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.6.64)
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 University of Amsterdam.
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- ['helloworld.prolog'].
% helloworld.prolog compiled 0.00 sec, 1,376 bytes
true.

?- helloworld.
Hello World!
false.

?-
```

Notice that you have to consult the file first. I tried this out and it works for sure.

Comment: I don't think so, I changed the program to Write:-write("hi") and it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Alright, how do I print anything? I want to do a simple "hello world".

Comment: You can't start a procedure with an uppercase letter. Change your code to `hello_world:-write('hello world'),nl,fail.` Notice that I'm starting the procedure with a *lower-case* letter.

Comment: In what directory are you saving helloworld.prolog? Why are you using the .prolog extension? My SWI only recognizes files with the .pl extension.

Comment: In the same directory where I'm calling `prolog`. I used `.prolog` as an arbitrary extension. SWI Prolog didn't complain. You can change it to `.pl` and it should still work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to name the procedure `write`, not `Write`. Upper case starting letters are for variables. (It might be less confusing if you call it something else like `writeHi` or something, so it doesn't have the same name as a built-in procedure, but it will still work when you call it `write` because your write has a different arity than the built in one).

Also you might want to replace `"hi"` with `'hi'`, though it will work either way (but only the second version will actually print the word hi to the screen - your version will print it as an integer list).

Comment: Nah, I changed the clause to writehello:-write("hi"). and now it's printing: ERROR: Undefined procedure: writehello/0. I think the problem is the physical location where I'm saving the clause. Btw, I'm not sure but I think it's more correct to call it "clause" than "procedure".

Comment: @dmindreader: Well, you have to load (`consult`) the file before you try to invoke it. I guarantee you that it works with the lower case name. I actually tried it.